# How to get spring boot default Kafka consumer object

Tags: java, spring-kafka, spring-boot-actuator, spring-boot-test

My configurations for Kafka consumer are in the application.yaml file. I know that if I only have 1 consumer, I don't need to create a consumerFactory bean and it would be set by spring by default.
I need to test my consumer so I need to access the consumer object in my test file and I don't want to config it again (I want to use the default configuration in the application.yaml) file to create a consumer object. How is this possible?

Comment: Why do you need the consumer itself? You usually attach a listener annotation to components' consumer methods.

Comment: I am using it for integration test. I send a message to Kafka and want to see if the message is there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring Boot provides a comprehensive enough auto-configuration for Spring Kafka: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.3/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-kafka.

There is this set of beans you can inject into your test class:

- `KafkaTemplate<?, ?> kafkaTemplate`
- `ProducerListener<Object, Object> kafkaProducerListener`
- `ConsumerFactory<?, ?> kafkaConsumerFactory`
- `ProducerFactory<?, ?> kafkaProducerFactory`
- `KafkaTransactionManager<?, ?> kafkaTransactionManager`
- `KafkaJaasLoginModuleInitializer kafkaJaasInitializer`
- `KafkaAdmin kafkaAdmin`
- `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer kafkaListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer`
- `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<?, ?> kafkaListenerContainerFactory`
- `KafkaStreamsConfiguration defaultKafkaStreamsConfig`
- `KafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer kafkaStreamsFactoryBeanConfigurer`

So, to get a `KafkaConsumer` in your test, you need to autowire a `ConsumerFactory` and call its `createConsumer()` and you'll get a fresh instance based on the configuration properties.

Comment: I have set the default topic in the application.yaml:
  kafka:
    template:
      default-topic:events
But, I still get this error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Consumer is not subscribed to any topics or assigned any partitions

Comment: That’s correct. I assumed you know how to use KafkaConsumer... so, just subscribe it to your topics and go on with testing!